# Size discrepancy between df -h output and lsblk output

Tags: partition, disk-usage, fdisk, storage, lsblk

When I run `df -h` and `lsblk`, on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Oracle Cloud instance, there is a discrepancy between sizes of my /dev/sda1 mount. I am not sure if this has to do with GiB vs GB or something else. I am hoping someone could provide some insight on this. Thank you for your time!

df -h (Human readable)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G  1.4M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       194G   82G  113G  42% /
tmpfs            12G  4.0K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/12605
/dev/loop2       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core20/1274
/dev/loop1       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/core18/2289
/dev/loop4       61M   61M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21843
/dev/loop3       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core20/1332
/dev/sda15       98M  290K   98M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop5       21M   21M     0 100% /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/29
/dev/loop6       21M   21M     0 100% /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/31
/dev/loop7       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/core18/2252
/dev/loop8       38M   38M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14296
/dev/loop9       38M   38M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14553
tmpfs           2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/user/1001
```

lsblk

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0  97.4M  1 loop /snap/core/12605
loop1     7:1    0    49M  1 loop /snap/core18/2289
loop2     7:2    0  57.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1274
loop3     7:3    0  57.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1332
loop4     7:4    0  60.7M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21843
loop5     7:5    0  20.6M  1 loop /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/29
loop6     7:6    0  20.7M  1 loop /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/31
loop7     7:7    0    49M  1 loop /snap/core18/2252
loop8     7:8    0  37.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14296
loop9     7:9    0  37.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14553
sda       8:0    0   200G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0 199.9G  0 part /
└─sda15   8:15   0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
```

df (Non-human readable)

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            12240312        0  12240312   0% /dev
tmpfs            2457200     1376   2455824   1% /run
/dev/sda1      203048660 85160388 117871888  42% /
tmpfs           12285984        4  12285980   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           12285984        0  12285984   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         99840    99840         0 100% /snap/core/12605
/dev/loop2         58880    58880         0 100% /snap/core20/1274
/dev/loop1         50176    50176         0 100% /snap/core18/2289
/dev/loop4         62208    62208         0 100% /snap/lxd/21843
/dev/loop3         58880    58880         0 100% /snap/core20/1332
/dev/sda15         99801      290     99511   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop5         21120    21120         0 100% /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/29
/dev/loop6         21248    21248         0 100% /snap/oracle-cloud-agent/31
/dev/loop7         50176    50176         0 100% /snap/core18/2252
/dev/loop8         38400    38400         0 100% /snap/snapd/14296
/dev/loop9         38528    38528         0 100% /snap/snapd/14553
tmpfs            2457196        0   2457196   0% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Thank you for linking me those resources. I forgot to mention that I had Googled and one of the suggestions was to try growing the file system by typing “resize2fs /dev/sda1” However it lead to this error.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 52402939 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!”

Comment: What your filesystem type? You can check by running `df -hT /`. Also check the number of max inodes on the filesystem, `df -i /`.

Comment: Thank you guys for bringing my attention to inodes, I had no idea about this!